# How to detect changed part of multiple texts

Tags: php

I got multiple string in array where I should find what part (=words) are changed (what are changed text and where it is located). What algorithm I should use?

input

```
$strings = [
    'a' => 'Blah blah. Value of something is 123456 and it is about 50%.',
    'b' => 'Blah blah. Value of something is 10203 and it is about 75%.',
    'c' => 'Blah blah. Value of something is 9999 and it is about 500%.',
    // more rows like this
];
```

output

```
$output = 'Blah blah. Value of something is [a=123456|b=10203|c=9999] and it is about [a=50%|b=75%|c=500%].';
```

(Yes, I'm going to add some fancy Html mouseover at some point ..)

---

Currently I'm doing some experiments with [PHP-FineDiff](https://github.com/gorhill/PHP-FineDiff), but It's huge mess if I want to compare more than two strings with each-other. (Should I write some huge loop to check characters one at time or try regular expressions or .. ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you a bit closer to finding the answer; you can split up each sentence into arrays of words, then run `array_diff()` on them collectively. Finally you combine the words together and create arrays where you found a match earlier:

```
$strings = [
    'a' => 'Blah blah. Value of something is 123456 and it is about 50%.',
    'b' => 'Blah blah. Value of something is 10203 and it is about 75%.',
    'c' => 'Blah blah. Value of something is 9999 and it is about 500%.',
];

// turn sentences into arrays of "words" (adjust where necessary)
$tmp = array_map(function($arr) {
    return explode(' ', $arr);
}, $strings);

// find collective differences
$diff = call_user_func_array('array_diff', $tmp);

// build final result
$result = [];
foreach ($tmp as $id => $words) {
    foreach ($words as $index => $word) {
        if (isset($diff[$index])) {
            $result[$index][$id] = $word;
        } else {
            $result[$index] = $word;
        }
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

#### Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Blah
    [1] => blah.
    [2] => Value
    [3] => of
    [4] => something
    [5] => is
    [6] => Array
        (
            [a] => 123456
            [b] => 10203
            [c] => 9999
        )

    [7] => and
    [8] => it
    [9] => is
    [10] => about
    [11] => Array
        (
            [a] => 50%.
            [b] => 75%.
            [c] => 500%.
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd explode the string into words, and compare the arrays:

```
$strings = [
    'a' => 'Blah blah. Value of something is 123456 and it is about 50%.',
    'b' => 'Blah blah. Value of something is 10203 and it is about 75%.',
    'c' => 'Blah blah. Value of something is 9999 and it is about 500%.',
    // more rows like this
];
$strings_exploded = [];
foreach ($strings as $i=>$string) {
    $strings_exploded[$i] = explode(' ', $string);
}

if (count($strings_exploded[0]) {
    $strings_numbered = array_values($strings); // much easier to iterate numbered arrays
    foreach ($strings_exploded[0] as $i=>$string) {
        for ($j = 1; $j < count($strings); $j++) {
            $compare_exploded = explode(' ', $strings_numbered[$j]);
            if ($strings_exploded[0][$i] == $strings_numbered[$j][$i])
                // same word
            else
                // different word, add it to a difference string maybe?
        }
    }
}
```